# Parsing string to array and display it on page

Tags: php, parsing

I have this string that used with simple html parser and something like this

```
<b>Atmosp'Hair, Caroline Michellod</b><i> in <a href="1" target="_top">Leytron</a></i>, Einzelunt., <a href="1" target="result">+++</a>, <a href="google.com" target="_blank">CHE-137.645.261</a><a href="pdf" target="_blank">Download pdf</a>
<b>Bar La Gouttière, Y. Maret</b><i> in <a href="http://www.example.com">Dolor</a><a href="2" target="_top">Martigny</a></i>, Einzelunt., <a href="2" target="result">+++</a>, <a href="yahoo.com" target="_blank">CHE-112.712.556</a><a href="http:/wwww.coocc.com">Doloo</a>
<b>Catherine Michellod</b><i> in <a href="3" target="_top">Bagnes</a></i>, Einzelunt., <a href="3" target="result">+</a>, <a href="bing.com" target="_blank">CHE-111.755.770</a><a href="pdf" target="_blank">Download pdf</a>
```

What i need is to get new array from this and display it on page to be like this

```
<a href="google.com" target="_blank">CHE-137.645.261</a>
<a href="yahoo.com" target="_blank">CHE-112.712.556</a>
<a href="bing.com" target="_blank">CHE-111.755.770</a>
```

I have tried to find attribute _blank, but there is sometime another link with that attribute, also have tried to find nt child but there is sometimes another a tag. A lot of bad HTML, only thing that is unique is that a href inner html starts with **CHE**

Comment: Find all links and select those, which text starts with `CHE`

Comment: Yes, put in array and display it like this <a href="LINK">CHE NAME</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to get all matches, e.g.

```
<?php

    preg_match_all("/<[^>]*>CHE[^<]*<[^>]*>/", $str, $m);
    print_r($m[0]);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <a href="google.com" target="_blank">CHE-137.645.261</a>
    [1] => <a href="yahoo.com" target="_blank">CHE-112.712.556</a>
    [2] => <a href="bing.com" target="_blank">CHE-111.755.770</a>
)
```

Comment: Can you help me to get array like this
$results = Array =(
Array
(
    [link] => google.com
    [name] => CHE-137.645.261
)
Array
(
    [link] => yahoo.com
    [name] => CHE-112.712.556
)
Array
(
    [link] => bing.com
    [name] => CHE-111.755.770
))

Comment: @MiomirDancevic Just change out the `[]` array syntax with `array()`

Comment: can you write it, because i have tried still errors?